# How to process multiple products sale through Paypal PHP API

Tags: php, rest, paypal, paypal-sandbox, payment-processing

I am trying to sell multiple products through the [Paypal API](https://github.com/paypal/rest-api-sdk-php), but I get bad request errors.

I have items in a array like

```
 $products = array( 
   array('name' => 'Product 1', 'price' => $200) , 
   array('name' => 'Product 2', 'price' => $240) 
 );

$transactions = [];
$total = 0;
foreach($products as $product) {
    $transaction = new Transaction();
    $transaction->setAmount(array('currency' => 'USD', 'amount' => $product['price']));
    $transaction->setDescription($product['name']);
    $transactions[] = $transaction;
    $total += $product['price'];
}


$redirectUrls = new RedirectUrls();
$redirectUrls->setReturnUrl($returnUrl);
$redirectUrls->setCancelUrl($cancelUrl);

$amount = new Amount();
$amount->setCurrency($currency);
$amount->setTotal($total); 

$payment = new Payment();
$payment->setRedirectUrls($redirectUrls);
$payment->setIntent("sale");
$payment->setPayer($payer);
$payment->setTransactions($transactions);
```

How can I make the above code work? Your input is highly appreciated.

**More details:**

My approach is based on the following [example](https://github.com/paypal/rest-api-sample-app-php/blob/master/app/common/paypal.php#L111-L142) and [Paypal Rest API](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/api/).

Answer (score 0):

Solved by introducing/setting items and item lists objects. My code  now looks like this:

```
$item = new Item();
$item->setQuantity(1);
$item->setName($paymentDesc);
$item->setPrice($total);
$item->setCurrency($currency);
$item->setSku('HELLOWORLD');

$item2 = new Item();
$item2->setQuantity(1);
$item2->setName('Additional product');
$item2->setPrice($total);
$item2->setCurrency($currency);
$item2->setSku('HELLOWORLD2');

$item_list = new ItemList();
$item_list->setItems(array($item, $item2));

$transaction = new Transaction();
$transaction->setAmount($amount);
$transaction->setDescription('Payment description test');
$transaction->setItem_list($item_list);
```